# OnEditorActionListener not working even with maxLines=1 and imeOptions set on GO or DONE

Tags: java, android

i tried for hours to intercept the "enter" button on the keyboard but it just doesn't work. I know there are a lot of questions similar to mine but none of those answers solved my problem.

Here is my Edit Text xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_toolbar_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_15"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_toolbar_search_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img_toolbar_cancel_search"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_toolbar_search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_toolbar_search_background" />
```

then, after i bind the view using Butterknife i set the listener in the OnCreate method of the activity 
 like this:

```
etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {

   /*if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {*/

        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    });
```

I have another app where i've done this some months ago and there it works flawlessly(xml is literally copied from there) so my phone keyboard/Android version shouldn't be a problem.
I know singleLine is deprecated, but someone suggested to add it - doesn't work with or without it.
I've already tried switiching imeOption to every other action, still won't work.
I commented the IF because i thought maybe it was wrong, but the listener is literally never triggered.

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after hours & hours i finally solved it. The problem was that inside the activity i had a fragment that also overrode the EditorListener so i guess it also overrode the one in the activity. Anyway, deleteing the listener in the fragment solved my problem